# Clarification needed for a set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question with regards to this problem:
Let $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and let $P(A): A \cap \{2,4,6\} = \emptyset$ and $Q(A): A \neq \emptyset$ be open sentences over the domain $\mathcal{P}(S)$.

a) determine all $A \in \mathcal{P}(S)$ for which $P(A) \land Q(A)$ is true

b) Determine all $A \in \mathcal{P}(S)$ for which $P(A) \vee ~Q(A)$ is true.

The solutions stated that for part a) it includes all nonempty subsets of $\{1,3,5\}$ which I assume is simply the same as: $A = \{\{1\},\{3\},\{5\},\{1,3\},\{1,5\},\{3,5\},\{1,3,5\}\}$.

As for part b), the solution states that it can be all possible subsets of $A = \{1,3,5\}$, which I believe means the $\mathcal{P}(A)$ ? However, I don't get the case why for part a, the solution does not include the $\emptyset$ as being in A too. I understand that it is in order for the statement $Q(A)$ to be true because it is a conjunction but I thought that $A \neq \emptyset$ means that the entire set of $A$ cannot be equal to the $\emptyset$. That is, $A = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{3\},\{5\},\{1,3\},\{1,5\},\{3,5\},\{1,3,5\}\}$ will still make the statement $Q(A)$ true.

This is a slight confusion and it would be nice if someone clarify this for me and I hope my question is understandable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to b), only one of them needs to be true. Then empty set $\emptyset$ makes $P(A)$ true, and any non-empty subset of $S$ makes $Q(A)$ true. $Q(A)$ is **not** true for $A = \emptyset$, by definition.

So **all** subsets of $S$ make one of them (at least) true. Note that the domain is $\mathcal{P}(S)$.

Comment: Oh i see so I guess if $A$ contains the $\emptyset$, then it will automatically make the statement $Q(A)$ false. Then, $A = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{3\},\{5\},\{1,3\},\{1,5\},\{3,5\},\{1,3,5\}\}$ will also make $Q(A)$ false correct? However, would $A = \{ \{\emptyset,1\}\}$ as an example also make $Q(A)$ false ? I think I am slightly confused over the fact that $A = \emptyset$ as opposed to something like $\emptyset \subset A$

Comment: You're confused. Your $A$ is not an element of $\mathcal{P}(S)$. $A$ should be just a single subset of $S$, i.e. an element (not **subset**) of your domain. And for a single set it's easy to check whether it is disjoint from $\{2,4,6\}$ or equal to the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Note the distinction between the set $U \subset \mathcal{P}(S) = \{A \in \mathcal{P}(S):P(A) \wedge Q(A)\ = \text{true} \}$ which you're looking for in part a), and each set $A$ contained in $U$. Conceptually, think about what $U$ really is: The subset of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ in which all sets $A$ satisfy both sentences $P$ and $Q$ are satisfied. Therefore, $U$ is really a set of individual sets $A$, all of which neither contain $2,4,$ nor $6$ and are nonempty. So $U$ can't contain the empty set because then there would be a set $A \in U$ such that $Q(A)$ is false.

Now, when approaching (b), you can immediately recognize that the only set to be gained by relaxing the constraint on $U$ from $P(A) \wedge Q(A)$ to $P(A) \vee Q(A)$ is the one set which satisfied only one of $P(A)$ and $Q(A)$: the empty set. So your set $V$ for (b) is simply $U \cup \{\emptyset\}.$